# Loc argument in pandas (contains and not contains )

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I was wondering how can we add str.contains arguments and str.notcontains in the same tab.loc command line ?
The idea is to selected row in a dataframe where the columns contains a value and does not contains others.

I tried :

```
tab2=tab.loc[tab['COL1'].str.contains('A',na=True) & tab['COL2'].gt(0.05) & ~tab['COL3'].str.contains("B") &  ~tab['COL4'].str.contains("C")]
```

error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`

or

```
tab2=tab.loc[tab['COL1'].str.contains('A',na=True) & tab['COL2'].gt(0.05) & tab['COL3'].str.contains("B") == False &  tab['COL4'].str.contains("C") = False ]
```

error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

but it does not work...

Here is an exemple

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A    0.9  E    F
A    0.9  B    F
B    0.9  E    F
A    0.02 B    C
A    0.3  D    B
```

here I should only keep

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4
A    0.9  E    F
A    0.3  D    B
```

Comment: show an MRE with expected output

Comment: Why ? it is a simple question, it does not need an input/output... I edited the question to be more precise

Comment: did you try adding parenthesis around each condition?

Comment: it does not work that way is not it ?

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work, it shows an error or it yields an empty dataset?

Comment: @ombk I added the error in the post

Comment: if you can post a part of ur data we could work it out. however, im pretty sure you can solve it by removing the iloc or loc, `df[(conditions) & (conditions)]`

Comment: I added one exemple

Answer (score 0):

```
data2= pd.DataFrame({"COL1":["A","A","B","A","A"],
"COL2":[0.9,0.9,0.9,0.02,0.3],
"COL3":["E","B","E","B","D"]})

data2[(data2.COL1=="A")& (data2.COL3 != "B")]
# data2[(data2.COL1.str.contains("A"))& (data2.COL3 != "B")]

#output
  COL1  COL2    COL3
0   A   0.9      E
4   A   0.3      D
```

Comment: Thanks but here it is an example, I realy need the contains part since the values I want to avoid or keep are note extaclty ==